# JavaScript new Date() Returning NaN in IE, Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, internet-explorer, highcharts

I am using highcharts to draw charts and parsing the date with `new Date()` function. In Chrome and FF, date is parsing fine.

But in IE and Safari, i am getting **NaN and Invalid date format** resp.

Below is the data i am getting from backend in (element.x) array

```
2016, 04,05
2016, 04,06
2016, 04,07
2016, 04,08
2016, 04,09
2016, 04,10
```

Now, i am converting it to Date object in JavaScript as below:

```
//Loop starts
var xAxis = new Date(element.x);
datas.push([Date.UTC(xAxis.getUTCFullYear(),xAxis.getUTCMonth(), xAxis.getUTCDate())]);
//Loop ends
```

Now, this operation returns **NaN** in IE but works very well in chrome as below:

**Chrome**

```
Array([0]=>140004454) - Unix Time stamp i get
```

**IE**

```
Array([0]=>NaN)
```

Comment: Once you correctly parse the string, if you want an array of the time values, simply do `datas.push(+xAxis)`, which will coerce the Date to a number, returning its time value. Or use `xAxis.getTime()` if you want something clearer.

Comment: But the problem was with new Date() function. It was not parsing date correctly.

Comment: Hence why it's a comment, not an answer—I'd already given John a +1. :-) Just thought I'd save you a heap of typing and unnecessarily calling Date.UTC.

Comment: and yes,,, This also worked.. doind +xAxis after correct parsing..  Awesome :)

Comment: What is good to use .. +xaxis or xaxis.gerTime()

Comment: Per the the first comment. *+xAxis* is less to type but perhaps *xAxis.getTime()* is better for maintenance as it's explicit. Your choice. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way `new Date(dateString)` parses `dateString` varies for different browsers, with some browsers being more flexible than others.

The safest way to create your date, is to...

1. split up your `element.x` into its components
2. convert those components to integer values
3. create a new date using the syntax `new Date(year, month, day)`

So, instead of ...

```
var xAxis = new Date(element.x);
```

... create your date like this :

```
var xvals = element.x.split(',');
var xAxis = new Date(
    parseInt(xvals[0]),
    parseInt(xvals[1]) - 1,
    parseInt(xvals[2])
);
```

That should work in all browsers!

Comment: Plus one for parsing the values. BTW, there's no need for *parseInt*.

Comment: @JohnSlegers—the specification doesn't specify integers. [*ECMA-262 §20.3.2.1*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds-ms) requires *ToNumber* to be called on each value, regardless of its type, so strings are fine. Applaud your motives though.